# For a family of sets $\mathbb{U}$, $\cup_{arbitrary}(\cap_{finite} U)$ $\forall U \in \mathbb{U}$ is stable under $\cap_{finite}$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request

The weak topologies of a Banach Space are constructed by taking a family $\tilde{B}$ consisting on all finite intersections of $\mathbb{U}$ and then taking arbitrary unions of sets of $\tilde{B}$.

I want to show that this is indeed a topology, for which I need to show that the family constructed is stable under finite intersections.

Can someone provide me some reference (or sumarize the steps to do it myself )on how to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right) \cap \left(\bigcup_{j \in J} B_j\right) = \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (A_i \cap B_j)$$

so that the intersection of two unioned families is again a unioned family, over a bigger index set, and if the $A_i,B_j$ come from a family which is closed under finite intersections, the latter is also a union from that.

So if we have $\mathcal{B}'$ equal to all finite intersections from a family $\mathbb{U}$, then $\mathcal{B}'$ is closed under finite intersections as well.

And then the above identity shows that the family of *all* unions from such a family is closed under the intersection of two members.

Proof of the identity: suppose $x$ is in the left hand side. So $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ so there is some $i(x) \in I$ such that $x \in A_{i(x)}$. Also, from the intersection, $x \in \bigcup_{j \in J} B_j$, so $x \in B_{j(x)}$ for some $j(x) \in J$. But then $(i(x), j(x)) \in I \times J$ and $x \in A_{i(x)} \cap B_{j(x)}$, so $x$ is in the right hand union. The other inclusion is just the previous proof backwards.

The finite intersections are then also clear (any family closed under the intersection of two members is closed under the intersection of finitely many by induction).

Comment: How can I show the identity?

Comment: @D1X added some details.

Answer (score 1):

This is functional in general.

Let $X$ be a set an let $\mathcal V\subseteq\wp(X)$.

Then the collection of finite intersections of sets in $\mathcal V$ automatically has the [basic properties of a base of a topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Definition_and_basic_properties).

This in the understanding that the *empty* intersection equals $X$.

Denoting the collection by $\mathcal{V}^{\stackrel{\cap}{f}}$ we have $X\in\mathcal{V}^{\stackrel{\cap}{f}}$ so automatically $X$ is covered by the collection.

Secondly if $U,V\in\mathcal{V}^{\stackrel{\cap}{f}}$ then $U\cap V\in\mathcal{V}^{\stackrel{\cap}{f}}$.

Shown is now that the collection has the basic properties.

Then the topology itself is the collection of sets that can written as union of base elements. Let's denote it by $\mathcal{V}^{\stackrel{\cap}{f}^{\cup}}$

In short: for **every** $\mathcal V\subseteq\wp(X)$ the collection $\mathcal{V}^{\stackrel{\cap}{f}^{\cup}}$ is exactly the topology generated by $\mathcal V$.

---

Request: could someone by means of an edit be so kind to improve my ugly notation $\mathcal{V}^{\stackrel{\cap}{f}}$?

I can't find a $\cap$ symbol with letters under it.

Thank you.